# CSS on table not working

Tags: html, css, html-table, border

I have this HTML table:

```
<table width="1100" border="1" style="text-align:center;" class="invoice">

<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Amount Due</td><td>Amount Enc.</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>CAD <?php echo $key['remainingbalance']; ?></td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>

</table>
```

with this CSS:

```
table.invoice, th.invoice, td.invoice{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

however it's not styling my table, I am expecting all of the borders for the table, td and tr to be 1px solid black, why is this not working?

Comment: The cells don't have the class of `.invoice`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The border in your sample will *only* apply to the table.
1) table.invoice -- this refers to a table with the class "invoice"
2) th.invoice -- this refers to a header-cell with the class "invoice"
3) td.invoice -- this refers to a normal table-cell with the class "invoice"

so 2 & 3 don't apply, because you don't have that class on your table cells.

You could change the styles like this:

```
table.invoice, .invoice th, .invoice td{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table.invoice{border-collapse:collapse;} /* update following asker's comment */
```

... then the border will apply to the header-cell and the normal cell.

Comment: This works :) now is there away to get it single line and not double lined?

Comment: add: table{border-collapse:collapse; }  (if I understand you correctly)